# Foundation 5: Non-Nested Layout

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using the [Foundation 5 framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and am trying to solve an issue I'm having. Let's say I've got a layout like so.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-15 columns">
        <div class="large-9 columns">

        </div>

        <div class="large-6 columns">
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <p>stuff</p>
            </div>
            <div class="large-3 columns">
                <p>stuff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I stop the .large-3 columns from nesting? I want each .large-3 column to take half of its parent column (.large-6). Is this possibly, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First off, Foundation grids are 12 units wide, so unless you have built a custom grid, and written custom CSS for it, large-15 isn't going to mean anything.

That being said, this will split the right hand column neatly in half, using a 12-unit grid. Every row in the grid has to add up to 12, no matter how deeply it is nested. If you laid out the necessary structure for a 15-unit grid, the same principle would apply, although it would be much more difficult to split things in half.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='large-12 columns'>
    <div class='large-7 columns'>
      <p>stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class='large-5 columns'>
      <div class='large-6 columns'>
        <p>stuff</p>
      </div>
      <div class='large-6 columns'>
        <p>stuff</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I've written out a custom 15 col grid. I was wondering if there was a way to stop that nesting? As it adds extra margins that I don't care for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need block grid. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html.

If you create block grid using class "small-block-grid-2" and with two "li" then both li will take half of the available width.

Also I show your last comment, if you don't need margin then add collapse class to "row" div.

I hope this helps.